# magento 2 cloud 2.4.6 how change mariadb 10.6 utf8mb3 to utf8mb4 for each column and all tables

Tags: mariadb, cloud, magento2

1. I have one magento cloud project based magento 2.4.6
   Now I need to save Emoji string into customer firstname, address firstname, even billing address firstname. If not, it will show ??? at frontend page when people sso login from line or some other channels.
2. So whether it affect the functionality if i totally change each columns from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4?
3. It is possible to only change the affected columns in several tables?
4. If it is no affect for the total feature, how change by code instead of change manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you with the order items table, where customers can enter emojis for customization texts.
At that time, I changed that table collation manually, and with every setup:upgrade, I had to change it again.
About a year ago, I decided to change all tables' charset and collation, and it's still fine.
So, I think there is no problem in changing that for you until Magento supports it officially.

But I had a problem with a 3-rd party module. One of them was defined charset in `db_schema`, and there was no need for that, So I removed it from `db_schema`.:)

Here's my workaround:

First, you need a custom module.

In your custom module's di file (located in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`), add the below overrides:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table" type="Vendor\Module\Core"/>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Factories\Table">
        <plugin name="override_default_charset" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OverrideDefaultCharsetPlugin" sortOrder="1"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Create `Core.php` file in your module root (`app/code/Vendor/Module/Core`):

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class Core extends Table
{
    protected $_options = ['type' => 'INNODB', 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collate' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'];
}
```

You can change `collate` or engine type.

Then, you need to create a plugin to override the default charset. Create `OverrideDefaultCharsetPlugin.php` in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin`:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Factories\Table;

class OverrideDefaultCharsetPlugin
{
    private const DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf8mb4';


    // You can change the default Collation as you need.
    private const DEFAULT_COLLATION = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';

    /**
     * @param Table $subject
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeCreate(Table $subject, array $data): array
    {
        if (!isset($data['charset'])) {
            $data['charset'] = self::DEFAULT_CHARSET;
        }

        if (!isset($data['collation'])) {
            $data['collation'] = self::DEFAULT_COLLATION;
        }

        return [$data];
    }
}
```

At the end run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.