# whether magento 2.4.6 support utf8mb4

Tags: magento, mariadb, utf8mb4

currently i work magento website based 2.4.6.
when customer sso login from line, there are some EmoJi characters. When use utf8mb3, it show ???. We need change mariadb to be utf8mb4.
when run bin/magento setup:upgrade, got error:
[image]
But investigate the code in detail, find hard code
[image]
[image]
whether magento 2.4.6 support utf8mb4?

need use utf8mb4 to support Emoji characters

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77072324/10245455

Answer (score 0):

this is known issue that is not fixed yet.
Initially was reported https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35174 and it supposed to be fixed and delivered soon.